# What is the correct punctuation to use in this sentence?

Tags: lists, colons, em-dashes

> A strong adaptation of the metered billing models by the leading Software-as-a-Service providers demonstrate the advantages such billing models bringing to all stakeholders of the service: the service providers, the app developers, and the customers.

In the sentence, does the list "the service providers, the app developers, and the customers" after the colon correspond to the stakeholders or to the advantages of the metered billing model?

Does replacing the colon with an em dash change the meaning the sentence? e.g.

> A strong adaptation of the metered billing models by the leading Software-as-a-Service providers demonstrate the advantages such billing models bringing to all stakeholders of the service — the service providers, the app developers, and the customers.

How do I write this sentence correctly if I want the list to correspond to the stakeholders?

Also, I am wondering what puncutation should I use to make the list correspond to the advantages of the metered billing model. e.g.

> A strong adaptation of the metered billing models by the leading Software-as-a-Service providers demonstrate the advantages such billing models bringing to all stakeholders of the service: flexibility, cost saving, and easier migration.

Comment: Your sentence seems flawed. Is "A strong adaptation" supposed to be the subject and "demonstrate" the main verb? It's not clear what that means, but if it is the subject, the verb should be "demonstrates" because it's singular, and it should be "bring" not "bringing". Current punctuation is OK, although rewording or dividing the sentence might be a good idea.

Comment: Logic leads the reader to understand what the series refers to in both cases.

Comment: The list is clearly the stakeholders. People can't be advantages.

Comment: And in your last example, they're clearly advantages, since flexibility, etc. can't be stakeholders. Without a complete rewrite, you can't disambiguate just with syntax, but common sense solves the problem. No reader should be confused by either of them.

Comment: A strong adaptation ... demonstrate**s** the advantages such billing models **bring** to all stakeholders...

Comment: I think a colon is the best option as it usually introduces a list in contemporary English. Using a dash or semicolon might suggest that "the service providers, the app developers, and the customers" were the subject of a new clause, and hence it's a bit confusing. You could also omit "of the service" if you think it's clearer without, as it's obvious which stakeholders are meant.

Comment: I suggest editing the question so that the sentence is grammatical, before addressing the punctuation question.

Comment: As a practical matter, how does a particular strong adaptation of metered billing models demonstrate the advantages of "such [underlying] models," as opposed to the advantages of "such [strong] adaptations"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A strong adaptation of the metered billing models by the leading Software-as-a-Service providers demonstrates the advantages that such billing models bring to all stakeholders of the service: the service providers, the app developers, and the customers.

This works, but it's a little difficult, as the first inclination is to link providers, developers, and customers to the nearby word "service" not the further out word "stakeholders." Since this makes no sense, the reader will go to "stakeholders" instead. Probably won't go to "models" as that's even further.

But let's go easy on the reader and make it more readable:

> A strong adaptation of the metered billing models by the leading Software-as-a-Service providers demonstrates the advantages that such billing models bring to all stakeholders: the service providers, the app developers, and the customers.

It's still needlessly long, but that's another issue.

Comment: Now that I look at it it's still a little tough, because it looks like we're talking about advantages and providers, developers, and customers aren't advantages! This would be easier:
...bring to all stakeholders (the service providers, the app developers, and the customers).